# iOS push notifications nightmares, Provisions app IDs and certificates

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Hey Apple developers, 
    I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how iOS provisioning profiles, certificates and app IDs work with push notifications. I thought I was close to getting this to work, but maybe not.

When I run my app and attempt to register push notifications, I get this error in the console:

```
2012-06-26 17:52:29.380 Grouped[1732:707] badgeNumber: 0
2012-06-26 17:52:30.089 Grouped[1732:707] [INFO] device is ready
2012-06-26 17:52:32.654 Grouped[1732:707] JSLOG: Registering with APNS via the App Delegate
2012-06-26 17:52:32.655 Grouped[1732:707] Register success callback set
2012-06-26 17:52:32.661 Grouped[1732:707] didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:Error 
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for 
application" UserInfo=0x18a0c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' 
entitlement string found for application}
```

I've done several hours of research now and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. 
I've created a new provisioning profile that is linked to my app ID. I can see it on my phone.

Any ideas?

Bonus question: Why on earth is it so complicated to properly provision an iOS app for push notifications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple things to check:

- Do you have any other provisioning profiles for this app on your device? I'd delete them.
- Does your App ID have push enabled in the provisioning portal?
- Are you sure you're signing with the correct profile? It has to be a non-wildcard  development certificate.
- Are you specifying your own entitlements.plist file? Modern Xcode generates one, so you don't need to do this. Make sure your "Code Signing Entitlements" build setting is empty.

If you haven't already found it, Apple has a good FAQ about this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: Hey Jesse, thanks for responding. I have two profiles on my device. One is my iOS team provision. The other is my push provision. Do I only need one? My app ID does have push enabled. In regards to your third question, what does that mean to sign the application with the correct profile? I made sure that my push provision profile did not have any wildcards. But my team profile does have a wildcard. Should I only be using the push provision? If so, how do I do that? I am not using my own entitlements.plist. Just everything default with the project. Any additional help would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: Look under your build settings for "Code Signing Identity" and ensure that it's selecting the non-wildcard profile for your target & scheme; you should only be using the non-wildcard one (it's OK to have the other around, just don't sign this app with it).

Answer (score 1):

```
"no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for 
application"
```

Your provision profile doesn't have push notifications enabled.  Make sure you enabled them in the provisioning portal, generate a new profile, but more importantly make sure you *actually installed it in Xcode and are signing your app with that profile*.  That last part has bitten me a couple times.

Comment: Interesting. So I haven enabled push in my profile. But as I mention in my response to Jesse's answer below, I have two profiles. My team provisioning profile and the push provision profile that I created for pushing (with push turned on). I downloaded the certificate and it's it shows up in xcode along with my team provisioning profile. How do I tell xcode not to use the team provisioning profile? Or is that not the answer? Thanks so much for responding. This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to create new adhoc/appstore profiles AFTER you created push certificates for your app. The distribution profiles change after enabling the App for push messages.